# why this code is false? and when it is tried using different M&N it id right!?

Tags: matlab

```
for X = 0: 0.00001 : 100;
    M=(((sqrt(2*X)-(1/3))^2)*(2*X-1));
    N=(( 10.99743/sqrt(X)-(23/30))^2)*(( 53.75263/X)-1);
    if  M == N
        Y=X;
    end
end
```

this code is for an equation with two sides M&N,,, it must be solved using try and error or Matlab Numerical
why this code is false?

Comment: This question doesn't *need* to be re-opened, since it already has an accepted answer, *but*, I disagree with the reason for closing it. The fact that OP doesn't know that floating point values can't be compared using `==` is not a reason to close the question, it is a reason to *answer* the question. OP has included his/her attempted solution and want to know why it doesn't work. IMO: *On*-topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is (as nkjt points out) with comparing floating point values with `==`.

FYI: If your objective is to find for which `X`, `M == N`, then you could do it much simpler using for instance [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html):

```
 f = @(X) (((sqrt(2.*X)-(1/3))^2)*(2.*X-1))- ...
          (( 10.99743./sqrt(X)-(23/30))^2)*(( 53.75263./X)-1);
   y = fsolve(f,1)
   y =  6.0304
```

This gives:

```
M - N = -1.3743e-05
```

Which is quite close to zero (as close as you will get).

If you absolutely want try and fail, see if you can decipher this (based on the idea of nkjt):

```
step = 1;
X = 1:step:100
M=(((sqrt(2*X)-(1/3)).^2).*(2*X-1));
N=(( 10.99743./sqrt(X)-(23/30)).^2).*(( 53.75263./X)-1);
[Y, idx] = min(abs(N-M))

err = 1e-10;   % Arbitrary tolerance > 1e-14 (typically)
it = 0;

while Y > err && it < 10
    step = step / 10;
    it = it + 1;
    X = X(idx) + (-step*10:step:step*10);
    M=(((sqrt(2*X)-(1/3)).^2).*(2*X-1));
    N=(( 10.99743./sqrt(X)-(23/30)).^2).*(( 53.75263./X)-1);
    [Y, idx] = min(abs(N-M))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The perils of floating point comparison could be one factor. When comparing two floating point numbers, you should not use `==` but check if the difference between them is less than some tolerance (can use `eps` or something else, depending on your requirements).

Rather than looping at very small steps across your entire range of possible values, you can vectorise, start with a coarser range of X values and get a much better idea of where your solution probably lies, for example:

```
X = 0:1:100
M=(((sqrt(2*X)-(1/3)).^2).*(2*X-1));
N=(( 10.99743./sqrt(X)-(23/30)).^2).*(( 53.75263./X)-1);
Y = abs(M-N);
plot(X,Y);
```

Then find the minimum difference between M and N, reduce your step size and range, and continue until you get to a value for X for which the value of abs(M-N) is below your tolerance (required accuracy of your solution).